# Crack in surface of varistor, likely bad?

Tags: surge-protection, varistor

I experienced a power surge at my house and some equipment stopped working. one device just had a blown fuse so I soldered in a new one and it worked fine. Another device had an obviously blown varistor and another one that just had a crack in its outer shell. I found the 07D221K and replaced it but couldn’t find the 10D221K so I replaced just the one.  This didn’t fix the issue. Is a varistor with a crack in the case a sign that it’s also toast? I also replaced the fuse.

Comment: For sure bad already or very little life left in it. Replace it.

Comment: Thank you winny for your fast response.

Answer (score 3):

A crack in the surface or coating of just about any components is an indication of stress, mechanical, thermal, electrical, etc.

So it's probably a safe assumption that your cracked varistor is bad.  What is not clear is which OTHER components were damaged by the same surge that took out your varistor.

Comment: Thank you I’ll try to find the other varistor locally and replace that too. I know have the control panel lights. Will keep looking.

Answer (score 1):

> *This didn’t fix the issue. Is a varistor with a crack in the case a
> sign that it’s also toast?*

It's not a good sign and it may well be broken but, given that both varistors mentioned are across the supply i.e. they are rated to withstand 120 volts AC power voltages, then it's unlikely that replacing it will fix the problem i.e. something else has blown.

[Varistor link](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/54/mov10d-777448.pdf)

Comment: Thank you so much andy for your reply. It’s a Panasonic desiccant dehumidifier that cost over 400.00 usd. It’s clearly worth a second or even third look if I can find the issue and repair it. So far it looks as if I had two bad varistor and a fuse but you’re probably correct. There are several motors in the device I’m just hoping they aren’t bad.